# Git commits associated with old, defunct user instead of the user I have now

Tags: git, github

My machine used to have an RSA key associated with a certain GitHub account, account_a.

I removed that key from my key chain, created a new key, added it to the chain, and then made sure that any other accounts I had on GitHub no longer had any SSH keys associated with them.

Note that the user on my machine has not changed.  I just created a new GitHub account and regenerated any keys, being careful to remove old keys from defunct accounts, just in case.

I expect my new commits to my brand new repo with my new account to reflect the user I am using now.  Instead they show up as one of my old, defunct accounts, like account_a.

I have no idea how to fix this, or even where it's coming from.

Comment: Did you changed your config `user.name` and `user.email` to reflect the new user?

Comment: @VonC I opened the gitconfig file using `git config --global --edit`, and indeed the email was one associated with an old account.  I changed that and everything is fine! Care to make this a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That association is more likely derived from your config `user.name` and `user.email`.

If you change those to relfect your new GitHub account, the commits should be associated with it.

The OP confirms:

> I opened the gitconfig file using `git config --global --edit`, and indeed the email was one associated with an old account.
>   I changed that and everything is fine!

You can also change it directly with:

```
git config --global user.email yourNewEmail
```